# How to set Typeface for a font in Xamarin MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

***I Have a custom `TextView`:***

```
            <Stella.Droid.Addons.CustomTextViewBaskervilleItalic
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#838383"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/ff_we_think_you_will" />
```

***CustomTextViewBaskervilleItalic.cs***

```
public class CustomTextViewBaskervilleItalic : TextView
    {
        private string text;
        public CustomTextViewBaskervilleItalic(Context context) :
        base(context)
        {
            Initialize(text);
        }
        public CustomTextViewBaskervilleItalic(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base(context, attrs)
        {
            text = context.Resources.ObtainAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.customfont).GetString(Resource.Styleable.customfont_textformat);
            Initialize(text);
        }
        public CustomTextViewBaskervilleItalic(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            text = context.Resources.ObtainAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.customfont).GetString(Resource.Styleable.customfont_textformat);
            Initialize(text);
        }
        void Initialize(string format)
        {
            Typeface leagueFont;
            if (format != null)
            {
                leagueFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, format);
            }
            else
            {

                leagueFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/Baskerville.ttc");
            }
            SetTypeface(leagueFont, TypefaceStyle.BOLD);
        }
    }
```

**The Options I have for my `Baskerville.ttc`**

[image]

---

***How can I set SemiBold font style from .ttc file***

Comment: Wouldn't you just amend this bit [  SetTypeface(leagueFont, TypefaceStyle.BOLD);  ] of your code?

Comment: But This is not setting the font from .ttc file for example if i make typeface italic .... characters are completely different

Comment: have you tried setting the font and type style after the control has been initialised? to determine if these properties are even set that early on in the controls instantiation.

Comment: I think this is exactly what you need: http://smstuebe.de/2017/02/12/mvvmcross-calligraphy/